# Type Casting Issue Using File Writer

Tags: java, string, methods, integer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KlQo.png)I have written a file writer and a file reader class in which you put data into and use it by file reader in another class methods. The type of my variable defined in Account class is integer.To write it in file, I change the type as String(because I have my other variables as String)...when I want to use that variable in my method in Account class, I can not compare it with the local variable(which is filled by user).It gives me a "NullPointerException" error. Can anyone help me with this?(The code is just a summary)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLxcq.png)

```
public class Account {
    int PIN;
public void meth_name(){
    int pin;

    if(PIN == pin)


    }
}

public class filewriter {

    public void met_name(){
        ....
        fw.write("PIN: "+ Integer.toString(PIN));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add things like `[SOLVED]` to a question title. Instead accept the answer that helped you (or if the question is not answered (but not on hold), post your own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java when you are working with [primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you cannot get `NullPointerException` because they are not pointers, they are allocated in [Stack Memory](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory).
So you are getting `NullPointerException` because some other variable is null. It is difficult to understand which variable is null from the code snipped you provided.
In your case `NullPointerException` might be thrown because

- The Account object which PIN you are acquiring is null
- The `fw`(filewriter) object which you are using is not yet initialized

Please provide more code or the stack trace of `NullPointerException` to understand exception's root cause.
Also please tell what is the type of `fw` object you used in the code. Is it `java.io.PrintWriter` or your custom class?

Comment: I added photos...

Comment: I assume the array `accounts` is null or there is such `i` for which `accounts[i]` is null. Add null-checks and test it. Also provide the exception Stack Trace.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you :D ... Could you please mark the answer as correct one if it really helped you?